# JQuery Onclick clear action value before submitting

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a form:

```
<form id="Myform" action="something here" method="post">

...

<input type="image" src="submit.png" id="mysubmit" name="submit" />
```

What I need the action value of the form to cleared before it submits.

How could I do that in JQuery?

Comment: Why are you setting an action that you don't want to submit to in the first place?

Comment: Maybe $('#MyForm').attr('action','');

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$("#Myform").submit(function(){
   $(this).attr("action","");
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I think what you are looking for is

```
$('MyForm').on('submit', function(){
    $(this).attr('method', '');
});
```

Comment: onsubmit should be submit & method should be action

Comment: I think it must be `$('#MyForm')`. Do we have `onsubmit` event in jQuery?